# How to replace string with a dictionary in YAML

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML which looks like this:

```
- k1: /etc/prometheus/auxiliaryfiles/mac-jwt-cne
  k2: abcd
  k3: 
  k4:
    z1:
     - asfa
  k5: zxcv
  key_001:
    __TARGETS__
```

and I have a dictionary which looks like:

```
{'a':[12,23,34]}
```

I want to replace `__TARGETS__` in YAML with the dictionary above so the resultant YAML should look like:

```
key_001:
 - a:
   - 12
   - 23
   - 34
```

My Code:

```
yaml_dict = readYaml("lib/above_Yaml.yaml")
d = {'a': [12, 23, 34]}
replacements = {'__TARGETS__':[d]}

for k, v in yaml_dict.items():
    if v in replacements:
        yaml_dict[k] = replacements[v]

dumped = yaml.safe_dump(yaml_dict)
print(dumped)
```

I get the following error:

```
     if v in replacements:
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: so you want the value of `key_001` to be a list, correct? not a dict?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: You shouldn't change your question in such a way that it becomes a moving target and is of no help to anybody. I removed my answer as it no longer applies. In any case you will never get the resultant YAML from that input, How do you suppose you get rid of the root level sequenc and keys `k1` through `k5` with your program? Where  is  the defintion of `readYaml()`?

Answer (score 0):

I would try with an approach using a *recursive* search and replace, like this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any

import yaml

yaml_str = r"""
  k1: /etc/prometheus/auxiliaryfiles/mac-jwt-cne
  k2: abcd
  k3:
  k4:
    z1:
     - asfa
  k5: zxcv
  key_001:
    __TARGETS__
"""


def recursive_repl(o: dict | list | Any, repl_dict: dict[str, Any]):
    """Recursively search and replace ``o`` with key-value pairs in ``repl_dict``"""
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        return {k: recursive_repl(v, repl_dict) for k, v in o.items()}

    if isinstance(o, list):
        return [recursive_repl(e, repl_dict) for e in o]

    return repl_dict.get(o, o)


d = {'a': [12, 23, 34]}
replacements = {'__TARGETS__': [d]}

# load yaml string into a dict
yaml_dict = yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)

# recursively search and replace with desired replacements
yaml_dict = recursive_repl(yaml_dict, replacements)

# convert back to a yaml string, and optionally write to file
dumped = yaml.safe_dump(yaml_dict)
print(dumped)
```

Out:

```
k1: /etc/prometheus/auxiliaryfiles/mac-jwt-cne
k2: abcd
k3: null
k4:
  z1:
  - asfa
k5: zxcv
key_001:
- a:
  - 12
  - 23
  - 34
```

Note: this requires [pyyaml](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/)

```
pip install PyYAML
```

Comment: Side-note: If performance is important, make sure to install the `yaml` and `yaml-dev` (or equivalent) packages for your system as well (PyYAML works without them, but the C accelerator won't be built so it will run slower). If performance doesn't matter (it probably doesn't, it's rare to do tons of YAML manipulation in a hot loop), then just the `pip` installation is enough (and it might be enough for certain systems if they have a binary wheel that bakes in the dependencies).

Comment: Although replacing after loading as YAML is a good idea, and PyYAML can handle this simple input example, you should inform the OP that if you use PyYAML, you are restricted to a subset of YAML 1.1, that you cannot have tags in your input, you'll lose any comments, special anchors/aliases, specific block/flow style and many other specifics formats that might exist in the original file.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. So, the output has to be - a: and not a: . Is there a way we can achieve this ? The '-' here is important

Comment: @MarceloBD no problem! see my updated answer above. I believe solution in this case is to make the replacement value into a list, so `[d]` instead of `d`.

Comment: Sure. Having a look

Comment: Hi @rv.kvetch , I have tried this approach and updated the question with the error. I should have elaborated the question in more detail as I think I missed some info that was trivial but I have added it now. Apologies, I am kinda new to PyYaml so didn't realise it

Comment: @MarceloBD no problem, I understand the problem now. It looks like you'll need recursion and also need to validate the type of values you're iterating over - since conceivably you could have other types like `dict` and `list` as nested values in the yaml too. please see my updated answer above.

Comment: @MarceloBD also just saw the note above by @Anthon. It's worth noting if you have any tags or comments in the yaml, this might get removed by this approach. One solution to work around this could be to use `ruamel-yaml` library instead of `yaml` - I believe the APIs are interchangeable as well.